# How to target only the Mouse with Logitech LED Illumination SDK

Tags: c#, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I want to Light just one key on my keyboard (Logitech G910),
at the same time as setting the color of the mouse (Logitech G303).

Setting a key on the keyboard works fine,
but I cannot set the color of the mouse without setting all keys on the keyboard to that color at the same time.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Response from Logitech via email confirms it's not possible to specifically target a compatible mouse if a compatible keyboard is connected.

Comment: Is it a feasible workaround to set all keyboard colors back after setting the mouse color? (Or does it flicker or something? I'm just curious for the sake of anyone seeing this.)

Comment: I tried it, and I can actually see no flickering. so it's a way forward.